# Find Principal curvature and Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

The task is:

Find Principal curvature and Gaussian curvature, mean curvature  and main directions. Find types of dots(points) on hyperboloid $f(u,v) = (a \cosh(u) \cos(v), a \cosh(u) \sin(v), c \sinh(u) )$

I'm not asking for a full solution, but any tips are highly appreciated.

Also the problem is that I translated task from another language so there might be some language misunderstandings..

Comment: that's probably the mean curvature instead of main?

Comment: @JohnMa actually I need to find a mean curvature as well but I didn't know what's it called so I didn't include it. But main curvature is there as well. It probably called not main, but something else.

Comment: Um...... principle curvature?

Comment: @JohnMa I think so, yes. Thanks for that.

Comment: @JohnMa: That's *principal*, not *principle*. One of my pet peeves.

Comment: You mean principal directions, too, @Alex. Anyhow, this is a standard calculation (although this one may get a little unpleasant). Take a look at any standard book on surfaces, e.g., my own free text you can get from the link in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

Let S be a regular surface, and let p be a point on
S. The maximum and minimum normal curvatures $k_1$ and $k_2$ at
p are called the principal curvatures of S at p. The corresponding
directions, i.e., unit eigenvectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ with $dn_p(e_i) = −k_i e_i$ , are called principal directions at p, where $dn_p= -g^{-1} L$. $g$ is the first fundamental form, while $L$ is the second fundamental form.
This means that you first compute $g$ and $L$, then $dn_p$. Since the first fundamental form is positive definite and
since $dn_p$ is self-adjoint with respect to this form, then by the Spectral Theorem, $dn_p$ is diagonalizable.You can then compute the eigenvalues of $dn_p$.
The Gaussian and mean curvature are related to $k_1$ and $k_2$ as a matter of factthe Gaussian curvature is
\begin{equation}
K= k_1 k_2 = det(dn_p)
\end{equation}
while the mean curvature is
\begin{equation}
H= \frac{k_1+k_2}{2} =-\frac{1}{2} Tr(dn_p)
\end{equation}
where Tr is the trace of the matrix $dn_p$.